# Calling a function based on an ID in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following function:

```
$('#topic').change(function()
```

It acts on an ID that's called #topic.   I would like to make this act on an ID called

```
#topic_1 or #topic_2 or #topic_3 etc.
```

Is there a simple way to do this with jQuery using wildcards?  Also how can I extract the number 1,2 or 3 and find out the value of another element labeled key_1, key_2 or key_3. I hope this makes sense to you.

Sorry it's a basic question but I am totally new to jQuery

Comment: I am sorry. I edited the question slightly and you were all so quick to reply. I like the idea of attribute starts with but how do I then find the _1 or _2 and add this to make a new ID of other elements?

Comment: i think it will better if you post new question for this...because evry one has given the answer according to intial requiremnt..now every one have to change there answer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `id` if you like (more options below), using the ["attribute starts with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('[id^="topic"]').change(function() { ... });
```

That selector will match any `id` value that *starts with* "topic". Be sure to put the argument ("topic") in quotes, it's (now) required.

If you have a short list of these, you may choose to simply list them directly:

```
$('#topic1, #topic2, #topic3').change(function() { ... });
```

Or you might choose some other characteristic they have in common. Popular choices:

- Their `class`, using the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

  ```
  $('.theClass').change(...);
  ```
- Their location in the DOM. For instance, if you want to watch the `change` event on all fields in a form, you can start with the form and use a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/), perhaps with a qualifier like [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) (which matches `input`, `select`, and `textarea` elements), like this:

  ```
  $('#formId :input').change(...);
  ```
- Some other attribute they share, using an ["attribute equals" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), ["attribute contains"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector, etc.

As you can see, you have [a lot to choose from](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), far more than just IDs and classes. Note that on most browsers, class selectors will be the fastest, but this only really matters on very complex pages or when you're looking up selectors a *lot*. Optimize if/when you see a problem, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a class selector instead? Gives all the elements a CSS class called "topic" and modify your code as follows:

```
$('.topic').change(function() { });
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$('input[id^="topic"]').val('news here!');

$(input[id^="topic"]).change(function(){

  //Do something

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use class attribute..

```
$('.topic').change(function() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a class selector is preffered way to do it. However, for arbitrary names you can also implement something similar to this:

```
for (i=0;i<blahblah;i++){

   $("#topic_"+i).change(function() {});
}
```