# How can I get the remainder of an ID when using jQuery attributes starts with

Tags: jquery, html

This is a follow up to my last question. Thank you very much for those answers. I had a bit more to ask so here it is in another question

If I use:

```
 $("[id^=topic]").change(function() { ... });
```

This gives me an ID that starts with topic. However I would like to find out what's left in the ID and then add this to something else.

In other words if an element with ID topic_1 changes then I would like to get the value of the element with ID key_1

How can I get the "_1" and add this.

Based on the suggestions I tried:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$("[id^=topic]").change(function() { 

var n= $(this).attr("id").split("topic_")[0];
alert(n);

});
```

and in my code:

```
<select id="topic_1">
                    <option selected="selected" value="cat" >cat</option>
                    <option value="dog">dog</option>
</select>
```

But nothing happens when I change the dropdown. Am I missing something?

Comment: looks like you forgot to wrap your `$("[id^=topic]").change(f` code inside document load. try putting that code inside `$(function (){ /*code here*/})` or at the end of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[id^=topic]").change(function() { 

var n= $(this).attr("id").split("topic_")[0];

});
```

Comment: I tried:     
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$("[id^=topic]").change(function() { 

var n= $(this).attr("id").split("topic_")[0];
alert(n);

});

Answer (score 0):

Inside function use `this` to get the current `'changed'` item

```
$("[id^=topic]").change(function() { 
  alert($(this).attr('id').replace('topic', ''));  
});
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mcGb5/1/).

Comment: what if the id is 'topic-topic1'? :p

Comment: @sv_in his topic is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700521/calling-a-function-based-on-an-id-in-jquery

Comment: I tried to implement the above but it seems not to fire when I change the value of the select. Hope somebody has an idea.